# Debugging type Errors in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function, returning all permutations from a list in Haskell:

```
perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = map (\y -> concat_each y (perms (list_without y xs))) xs

list_without :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
list_without x xs =
    filter (\y -> not (y==x)) xs

concat_each :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
concat_each x xs =
    map (\y -> x:y) xs
```

What I think happens in line3:
y is `a` and x is `[a]`, so
list_without y xs is `[a]`.

perms (list_without ...) is thus `[[a]]`

so concat_each y (perms ...) gets `a` and `[[a]]`, resulting in `[[a]]`

So the function for map is `a -> [[a]]` and everything should be okay.

But the compiler seems to see things differently:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
      at C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\permutations.hs:1:10
Expected type: [a]
  Actual type: [[a]]
Relevant bindings include
  y :: a (bound at permutations.hs:3:18)
  xs :: [a] (bound at permutations.hs:3:7)
  perms :: [a] -> [[a]]
    (bound at permutations.hs:2:1)
In the expression: concat_each y (perms (list_without y xs))
In the first argument of `map', namely
  `(\ y -> concat_each y (perms (list_without y xs)))'
```

How would I debug this error message properly? I don't really know where to start checking my types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]
```

The first argument you gave to `map` has type `a -> [[a]]`, i.e., `x = a` and `y = [[a]]` so

```
                :: [x] -> [  y  ]
map (\y -> ...) :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
                --  ^      ^^^^^
                -- x = a,  y = [[a]]
```

---

In this case, the result of that `map (\y -> ...) xs` is a list where each element corresponds to the permutations starting with a fixed element `y` in `xs`. In the end, you don't care which element a permutation starts with; you can forget that separation using `concat`:

```
perms = concat (map (\y -> ...) xs)

-- or

perms = concatMap (\y -> ...) xs

-- or

perms = xs >>= \y -> ...
```